# How to efficiently Import a table with blob columns from one database into another using Pentaho

Tags: oracle, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to copy a table data from one db to another db using pentaho, the copy works fine with sql loader for tables without blob data, i can see speed of upto 5000 records/ second.
However the same process with blob columns tables gives a speed of 70 records/ second.
I suppose the issue is at the source DB, I have millions of records to copy so this is not efficient, is there a way to improve this.
Interestingly if I convert my blob data into a string in the Select statement, the speed increases significantly, however since there is a limitation of 32767 chara for varchar2, I can't use that option.

Comment: Which database type? Since I had the same issue with postgresql and fixed it by using FDW's. Maybe good to mention it in the tags, since the core of the question is in the connectivity and functionality between pentaho and db.

Comment: @Bert-JanStroop, hey it is for Oracle DB, thanks, i have updated the question.